# Cant Get Out of For loop, it ignores break. have tried to change it but seem to just break my LED output

Tags: python, for-loop, raspbian, raspberry-pi4, bread-board

```
def shiftOut(dPin,cPin,order,val):
    
    for i in range(0,8):
        GPIO.output(cPin,GPIO.LOW);
        if(order == LSBFIRST):
            GPIO.output(dPin,(0x01&(val>>i)==0x01) and GPIO.HIGH or GPIO.LOW)
        elif(order == MSBFIRST):
            GPIO.output(dPin,(0x80&(val<<i)==0x80) and GPIO.HIGH or GPIO.LOW)
        GPIO.output(cPin,GPIO.HIGH);
        break
    
def loop():
    while True:
        for j in range(0,500): # Repeat enough times to display the bunny face a period of time
            x=0x80
            for i in range(0,8):
                GPIO.output(latchPin,GPIO.LOW)
                shiftOut(dataPin,clockPin,MSBFIRST,pic[i]) #first shift data of line information to first stage 74HC959

                shiftOut(dataPin,clockPin,MSBFIRST,~x) #then shift data of column information to second stage 74HC959
                GPIO.output(latchPin,GPIO.HIGH) # Output data of two stage 74HC595 at the same time
                time.sleep(0.001) # display the next column
                x>>=1
        for k in range(0,len(data)-8): #len(data) total number of letters columns 
            for j in range(0,20): # times of repeated displaying LEDMatrix in every frame, the bigger the "j", the longer the display time.
                x=0x80      # Set the column information to start from the first column
                for i in range(k,k+8):
                    GPIO.output(latchPin,GPIO.LOW)
                    shiftOut(dataPin,clockPin,MSBFIRST,data[i])
                    shiftOut(dataPin,clockPin,MSBFIRST,~x)
                    GPIO.output(latchPin,GPIO.HIGH)
                    time.sleep(0.001)
                    x>>=1
```

I'm using RPi and this code is imported into another file. It gets stuck in `shiftout()` and I don't know how to get out of the for loop in it and back into the file it's imported to.

Comment: What's the point of a loop that always breaks on the first iteration?

Comment: I doubt it's getting stuck in `shiftOut()`, since the loop never repeats. But nothing ever breaks out of the loop in `loop()`.

Comment: @Barmar I'm trying to get it display the image once (the image is text and a face that roll across) and the go to the next one according to pet.mood in another file

Comment: How do you get out of the `while True:` loop in `loop()`?

Comment: @Barmar i dont knowww